# imacros select from popup dropdown

Tags: imacros

Could you please help me :)

I have a TEXTBOX field which filling from a dropdown popup list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfaaE.png)

It's not a drop-down list where I could use TYPE=SELECT

It doesn't take it as just a text, it needs to be picking from the list.

If I record a macro, it gives me:

```
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:management_main    ATTR=ID:order_release/attribute1 CONTENT=201500
   TAG POS=2 TYPE=TR ATTR=TXT:201500
```

If I record a macro in Experimental event recording mode:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(6)>TD:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(6)>TD:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>INPUT" CHARS="201500"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(6)>TD:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>INPUT" KEY=13
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>DIV>DIV>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD" BUTTON=0
```

I've tried:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#order_release/attribute1" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#order_release/attribute1" CHARS="201500"
```

it doesn't work also...

Inspection of elements:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qQ79.png)

So still can't catch this event to fill that field...
Have you any idea for me?
I would be veeeeeery thankful)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that 'EVENT' mode is a right direction for you. It's just necessary to record a proper click on a certain item. (BTW, always provide the inspection of elements in the form of code (text) but not that of image.)

Comment: Could you provide us with a direct link, please?

Comment: Thank you for your responses!
@Valera Unfortunately, It's impossible to provide a direct link because it's a private web site of company.

Comment: @Shugar Ok, I'll provide a text for inspection of elements next time :)
And guys, I already have solved that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and it works:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:management_main ATTR=NAME:order_release/attribute1 CONTENT={{!COL7}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN FORM=NAME:management_main ATTR=ID:order_release/attribute1@ID CONTENT={{!COL7}}
```